# Rewriterule for any URL ending in specific format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all URLs ending in

`data.html` to `templates/data.php`

`info.html` to `templates/info.php`

`any_other_file.html` to `templates/index.php`

Again, all URLs ending with those names (could be `http://some-domain.com/some/long/path/data.html`)

Comment: And what have you tried? It's really quite simple...

Comment: I've managed to redirect all files to `template/index.php` with this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ template/index.php [NC,L]` but that's all I could do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in your **`/.htaccess`** file:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite data/info.html to the applicable PHP file
# in the templates directory
RewriteRule (data|info).html$ /templates/$1.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite everything else ending in .html to /templates/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /templates/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: this works great! one more thing pls: how do I actually make any url go to templates/index.php? not only those that end in .html; except data & info.html of course

Comment: i think i got it, just removed `.html` from the last line